# Package and module import in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, package

Here is my folder structure:

```
|sound
|-__init__.py
|-model
  |-__init__.py
  |-module1.py
  |-module2.py
|-simulation
  |-sim.py
```

The file module1.py contains the code:

```
class Module1:
    def __init__(self,mod):
        self.mod = mod
```

The file module2.py contains the code:

```
class Module2:
    def __init__(self,mods=None):
        if mods is None:
            mods = []
        self.mods = mods
    def append(self.mod):
        mods.append(mod)
```

Finally the file sim.py contains the code:

```
import sound

sound_1 = sound.module2.Module2()
```

When I execute sim.py I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sound'`

I've tried pretty much everything such as `from sound.model import module2` etc. but I believe the problem comes from python not finding the `sound` package.

I've read several tutos, docs and threads, and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: is sound a folder? is __init__.py inside it?

Comment: shouldn't be `sound.model.module2.Module2`  you are missing `model`

Comment: @Macintosh_89 already tried that

Answer (score 1):

#### The simple FIX :

- Move `sim.py` one folder up into sound
- Try `import module2`
- `sound_1 = module2.Module2()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I'd rather keep all the simulations in the same simulation folder